# Node.js Express Application Freezes When I Try to Access MongoDB Database from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose, and I am trying to do a simple test app that involves using Mongoose in order to familiarize myself with it. I can load up the "/" page fine, but when I submit the form, it stays on the "/" page until I terminate the process. The console.logs "before" and "after" print, but the during never does. What is wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'testmongoose');

var connectdb = function(execute) {
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function () {
        execute();
    });
};

connectdb(function () {
    var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        body: String
    });

    var Post = db.model('Post', postSchema);
});

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    //app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index');
});

app.post('/result', function(request, response) {
    var text = request.body.text;
    console.log("before!");
    connectdb(function () {
        console.log("during!");
        var post = "test";
        post = new Post({body: text});
        response.render('result', {text: post.body});
    });
    console.log("after!");
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since `connectdb` is an asynchronous function, it returns immediately and runs its callback later--meaning that the order of your `console.log`s will be "before!" then "after!" and then "during!" sometime later.

That said, `connectdb` isn't really serving you any use. Mongoose automatically buffers up commands until it connects, so you can treat it like a synchronous interface:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost', 'testmongoose');
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    //app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index');
});

app.post('/result', function(request, response) {
    var text = request.body.text;
    var post = new Post({body: text});
    response.render('result', {text: post.body});
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see! Was the issue that I was trying to connect to the server asynchronously? I really want to understand my mistake so it doesn't happen again. Is there a tutorial you recommend for Mongoose, because following the official quickstart got me in this mess. Also, can I still use a callback on the mongoose.connection.on if I do want it to do something once it connects?

Comment: Actually, on second checking, I still get a connection error: connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [mongodb://localhost:27017:27017]]... I have the server running.

Comment: The error says "mongodb://localhost:27017:27017"; are you putting the ":27017" in the connection host? If so, try leaving it off. If you want to do something once Mongoose connects, you can add an event listener to the `mongoose.connection` object that gets created when you call `mongoose.connect`. The list of events [is available here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection).